# React Table - Cannot access nested JSON object in Cell

Tags: reactjs, accessor, react-table, react-usememo

I have a problem with react-table.
I need to use subject.subjectName in a different column of the table, but I get an error that the value is empty

```
columns: [
   {
   Header: 'Subject Name',
   accessor: 'subject.subjectName' // displays properly in table
   },
   {
    Header: 'Delete grade',
    accessor: '_id',
    Cell: ({row: {values}}) => (
       <DeleteButtonWrapper>
          <DeleteButton
           onClick={async () => await deleteGrade(values._id)}>
             {values._id} // can access, displays _id properly
             {values.subject.subjectName}  // cannot access nested value: subject.SubjectName 
          </DeleteButton>
       </DeleteButtonWrapper>
       )
   }
]
```

Comment: I solved this problem as follows: Instead of referencing a nested object from values, I get the value after the index of object field: Object.values(values)[0]. - it works.

Comment: How did you integrate `Object.values(values)[0]` with `{values.subject.subjectName}` can you share your complete code?